# How to autoincrement the entered value of cell

Tags: excel, automation, vba

What I want is to autoincrement the entered value of cell.

Let's say i entered 3 in the cell but I want it to auto increment by let's say value 50 and new value would be 53
Any idea how can I do this ?

Comment: One cell or more than one cell ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks your vba code worked thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example for cell **B9**.  Install the following macro in the *Worksheet code area*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Intersect(Target, Range("B9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
      Target.Value = Target.Value + 50
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen @Gary's Student answer which is worth considering. I am only describing yet another approach. Select some range away from your working area. Say `R2:R100`   and fill it with worksheet fill series function in the increments you desire.
Your R2...R5 cell will have values say 7,14,21 etc. Now in Cell A2 use `=Row()+R2` and fill down as per your requirement. Your A2,A3,A4... will now have values as 9,17,24.... You can hide Column R so that it is not visible.